# Is it possible to create a playback session with multiple groups?

Tags: api, sonos

I would like to use the Sonos API to control which groups play music simultaneously (just like how you can select multiple groups to play music in the Sonos app). Is this possible? The createSession command looks like it only takes one groupId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, look at the [`groups`](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/groups/) namespace. Specifically, the [`createGroup`](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/groups/creategroup/) command, using the `musicContextGroupId` parameter, which should contain the group that has the audio to use.